# Parsing the output of a command

Tags: python

How do I parse the output of "df -h /local/mnt" to get the "Avail" data and exit from the script if its less than 150G?

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = ['df', '-h', '/local/mnt']

Pipe = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(output, error) = Pipe.communicate()

print "OUTPUT"
print output
```

Sample output of df -h /local/mnt

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       520G  324G  170G  66% /local
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Eg., using the string `.split()` method?

Comment: @ Evert - Yes, i was able to figure out how to run the command,do you have any pointers  on how to parse the output?

Comment: @sapam - yes it is linux

Comment: Ok please make sure to use this cmd: "df -Ph"  that will make sure your output in single line. else sometime you will get in two line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("df -h /", shell=True ).split('\n')[1]

data = output.split()[3][:-1]

if int(data) < 150:
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
output = os.system('df -h /local/mnt')
avail = list(reversed(output.split()))[4]
```

Here I am simply list(reverse()) the array of words so I need to do less work counting the spaces, but it doesn't really need to be done. Try it out, and change the index of [4] to another number

Comment: I get an error `TypeError: 'listreverseiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Sorry, the reversed doesn't return a list. you can can either just write output.split()[x] or do list(reversed(output.split()))[4] you have to count the spaces though. I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: am trying to get only the integer part  using `avail_space = available_space.rsplit('G')`  but I get the output as `['170', '']`,how to get `170' from `170G`..i tried using rsplit and it didnt work,i change avail to available_space

Comment: ok after you get the avail_space, then you can do this avail_number = avail_space[:-1], which removes the last character.